# Resolution for 2d pixel art games

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

I'm having problems to set the right resolution on unity to not have pixel distortion on my pixel art assets. When I create an tile grid, on the preview tab the assets look terrible.

[image]

I have an tilemap with 64x32 resolution for each tile.

I'm using 64 pixels per unit.

The camera size is set to 5 in a 640x360 resolution (using the following formula: vertical resolution / PPU / 2).

What I'm doing wrong and what I'm missing?

Comment: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/13/2d-pixel-perfect-how-to-set-up-your-unity-project-for-retro-8-bits-games/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem and get an "pixel perfect" view, you need to apply the following formula:

Camera size = height of the screen resolution / PPU (pixels per unit) / 2

This will do the job!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the tiles are defined, but assuming those are rects with textures on topm you could check your texture filter setting and play with it a little, setting it up for example to "anisotropic"