# How to Fix Pixel Stretching/Deletion in Unity 2D When PPU and PixelPerfect Camera Don't Seem to do the Trick

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've recently been tinkering with pixel art and tile-based games in Unity 2D, and after plenty of poking around to [figure out the correct import settings for my 16x16 sprites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dSDb.png) [Filter: Point (no filter), Compression: None, Pixels Per Unit: 16], I'm noticing that there's still some stretching/deletion of pixels. At the moment, I noticed it with a quick wooden plank tile I whipped up:
[A 16 by 16 pixel art plank tile with only one edge per plank so that the doubled pixels are not a result of the ends of two planks being next to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCp6b.png)

When looking at the 4 tiles in the bottom left in Unity's scene view, everything looks alright:

[A 4x4 TileMap section of the plank tile image in the scene view, with no stretching or deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX3ut.png)

However, when looking at those same tiles in the game view, some of the borders are thinner/thicker than others (red is notably thinner than blue):

[A 4x4 TileMap section of the plank tile image in the game view, with the borders between planks in the bottom row being about half as thick as the other rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfoYf.png)

Originally, I had my aspect ratio at some non-standard amount (1593 x 976 I believe) due to some free aspect movement I'd done earlier. I tried setting it to 1280 x 720, as I found at least one thread with a similar complaint that suggested an atypical aspect ratio would necessitate stretching/deletion when attempting to be pixel-perfect. That didn't resolve the issues in any way, nor did switching to a square aspect ratio of 720 x 720, so I switched back to 1280 x 720. I didn't particularly expect it to, since to my understanding, the aspect ratio only affects the viewport, and should have no bearing on how the sprites within that are rendered.

I then found a thread about the PixelPerfect camera component, which I then attached to my main camera. I set the assets PPU to 16 and made sure the reference resolution was 320 x 180 as the tutorial specified (I assume because that's a 16:9 ratio). Settings pictured here:

[Screenshot of the PixelPerfect camera component settings, as described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUF9X.png)

I even tried checking and unchecking both the Pixel Snapping and the Upscale Render Text options then saving, with no effect. Admittedly, by that point I was just clicking buttons without much understanding of what they were doing.

So, even with crisp pixel art import settings, and what I believe to be a correctly set up PixelPerfect camera, I'm still seeing stretching (or maybe deletion) of pixels when I'm aiming for something pixel-perfect. I'm sure I can make things work with minor faults like this, but if there's a solution, I'd like to know it.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing to answer my own question so quickly - turns out, the solution had to do with my camera. I'd changed the size previously without full understanding of it, and in the "Related Questions" to this post (though it didn't appear during the review phase of asking this question) I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292007/resolution-for-2d-pixel-art-games?rq=2) which suggested the following formula: Vertical Screen Resolution / PPU / 2

So for me, 720 / 16 / 2 = 22.5, which was about 5 times too big but resolved the stretching/deleting issues. I then divided by 5 and hoped that since it was in-ratio, it would work, and it did! So, a camera size of 4.5 rather than 5 and some change was the solution I needed.